# How do I render formatted datetimes from list of items with epoch times in local storage

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a list of items in localStorage that I pull in with `mounted()`, each item has two dates within it - in epoch time. I want to display these in a text field in a formatted way, with a date picker to accompany it when selected. I want that text-field to update the existing item if there is a change. I have tried over and over, but I just can't seem to get it going - I get errors here or missing items there. It has just been a mess. I've tried following the guide [here](https://codepen.io/prashanth1k/pen/eYmoraP) but I don't think it extends well to lists. What is the easiest way to get this going?

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      CARD TITLE
    </v-card-title>
    <v-btn @click="addItem()">
      Add Item
    </v-btn>
    <v-list>
      <v-list-item-group>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, i) in items"
          :key="i"
        >
          <v-card>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-col>
                <v-row>
                  <v-text-field v-model="item.Title" label="Title: " />
                </v-row>
                <v-row>
                  <v-text-field v-model="item.StartDate" label="Start Date: " />
                </v-row>
                <v-row>
                  <v-text-field v-model="item.EndDate" label="End Date: " />
                </v-row>
              </v-col>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-card>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

And then here is the javascript:

```js
<scrtipt>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      item: {
        Title: null,
        StartDate: null,
        EndDate: null
      },
      items: []
    }
  },

  watch: {
    localStorageItems: {
      handler(val) {
        this.items(val);
      },
      deep: tru
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('items')) {
      this.items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.items.push({ id: this.counter++ })
    },

    setLocalStorageItem(object) {
      localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(object));
    }
  }
}
</script>
```